# github : how to copy folder from fork to upstream?

Tags: git, github-for-windows

Can someone please help on this scenario?

From the upstream repository I've crated a fork.
In fork, I have created a folder and added files to the folder.

Now I want that folder and files in it copied to the upstream.

Can you please guide me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Create a Pull request where **base:** `upstream/master` and **compare:** `forked/master`.

1. Go to your forked repository and Create a Pull request.
2. Now, when the Pull request will be merged into `upstream/master` by authorized people then your `changes/folder` will appear in upstream repository.